# How to logrotate HHVM

Tags: php, nginx, centos, hhvm

How would youu logrotate HHVM logs?

Would you use /etc/logrotate.conf to do this?

I've tried below but this doesn't seem to be working. Also what do you need to do to reopen logs after rotate is complete?

```
/var/log/*.log {
    rotate 5
    daily
    compress
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    postrotate
        invoke-rc.d hhvm reopen-logs > /dev/null
    endscript
}
```

This is based on Ubuntu but I want something that we can use on CentOS server?

Is there a way we can find where pid is stored for current HHVM daemon?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used logrotate with HHVM yet, but you should be able to find the pid in `/var/run/hhvm/pid` assuming some run time config isn't changing that location.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've already tried that path but there doesn't seem to be `hhvm` folder inside `/var/run` folder. Is there a reason why?

Comment: How have you installed HHVM? I compiled from source on CentOS 6.5, and just created the dir myself.